# in flex, get function name from Function object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Given a Function object, can you get its name as a String?  See example:

```
function doThingWithCallback(callback:Function):void {
   trace("i'm going to run " + callback); // outputs "i'm going to run function Function() { }"
}

function foo():void {
   ...
}

doThingWithCallback(foo);
```

This example is sort of arbitrary, but it would be very useful to get function names for debugging, particularly when passing around Function objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the best answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711404/can-an-actionscript-function-find-out-its-own-name).

To my knowledge, the name of a function can only be determined while the function is on the callstack.