# Get the full name of a function given the function reference

Tags: actionscript-3, function, reflection

How do you get the full classpath of a static function in Actionscript, when given only the reference to the function? See the below code sample:

```
public class Tests {
     static function myFunc():void {}
}

var func:Function = Tests.myFunc;

trace(func.?) // should trace "Tests.myFunc"
```

Is this possible? Even the open source editor and debugger FlashDevelop can't do this. Try rolling over an object with a function ref, it shows the raw pointer (like 12341234) instead of the full name of the function. Of course with `describeType` you can get info about a type, ie. a *class reference*, but not when you only have a function ref. Given only a *function reference*, how do you get its name?

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731935/actionscript-obtain-the-name-of-the-current-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711404/can-an-actionscript-function-find-out-its-own-name

Comment: Incorrect. Those questions ask about getting the name of the CURRENT FUNCTION, whereas my question is about getting the name of a FUNCTION BY ITS REFERENCE (pointer)

Comment: Most importantly, you CAN use `getStackTrace` to get the name of the CURRENT FUNCTION, but this method would not work if you have a function pointer and need its name.

Comment: take a look on the first question with the _describeType_ approach, it utilize only reference to the function rather than the current one. Yes, you have to use _this_ or have reference to it somehow. In general it's impossible to get the function name

Comment: @Geotarget - I also think it's duplicate, because the first one describes the situation very well and explains when and only you can get a function name and how. Stack trace is not a proper way of doing it, and it's something like a small cheat for me :)

Comment: ok, I added answer with the example for the static function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in general, having only reference to the function (as mentioned in this accepted answer [Actionscript - Obtain the name of the current function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731935/actionscript-obtain-the-name-of-the-current-function)). There is only two ways to get the name:

1. using `describeType`, but in this case you have to provide the function host object. You can find example in the first answer [Actionscript - Obtain the name of the current function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731935/actionscript-obtain-the-name-of-the-current-function), I modified it for the static functions as well and utilizing `getSavedThis` that works in the debug player only:

   ```
   var name:String = getFunctionName( staticTest );
   trace("1", name);
   name = getFunctionName( staticTest, Astest ); //Astest the name of the class that hosts staticTest function
   trace("2", name);

   public static function staticTest():void
   {

   }

   public static function getFunctionName( func:Function, parent:* = null ):String
   {
       if(!parent)
       {
           //works only in debug flash player
           parent = getSavedThis(staticTest);
       }

       var methods:XMLList = describeType(parent)..method;
       for each ( var m:XML in methods)
       {
           if (parent[m.@name] == func)
               return m.@name;
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

output:

```
[trace] 1 staticTest
[trace] 2 staticTest
```

2. using *getStackTrace* (example in the same answer) but it works only in debug player and you have to be in the function closure.